# Why is my MySQL search query returning column names and data?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm fairly new to PHP and I've been stumped on this issue for a while now (been searching everywhere but no help really).

I'm attempting to search for all the data in a data table ("Select * FROM X") and that seems to work fine.

However when I try to return/echo the data, encoding into JSON format as an array (I'd like 1 row as 1 index in the array) it does wierd things.

Heres the code I currently use;

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `units`";
$Result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL) or die ("DB ERROR");
$Total = mysqli_num_rows($Result);
if($Total > 0)
{
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($Result);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
    {
        echo json_encode(array($row));
    }
}
```

This then gets used in Unity (C#) via;

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadUnitsWWW.text);
Debug.Log(obj);
```

The results of which are;

> [{"0":"2", "unitID":"2","1":"Tanks","unitName":"Tanks","2":"Ground","unitType":"Ground"},[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

it seems to be trying to return EVERYTHING for some reason, including the column names. But I've no idea why it'd return the same results multiple times (and no idea where the 0 came from).

As I said, I'm fairly inexperienced with PHP, as such its very likely something (in fact I'm certain) something is wrong with that code, I've tried a for loop such as;

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {...}
```

but to no avail (it returns something like:

> ["1",[],[],"",null,null,null,{},null,null,null.null[],""..........]

Heres the data table layout if it helps;

```
unitID | unitName | unitType

1 | infantry | Ground <br>
2 | Tanks | Ground <br>
3 | Support | Ground <br>
4 | Artillery | Ground <br>
. <br>
.
```

There are 13 items in the table

EDIT:

THis is what I am expecting:

> [["1", "Infantry","Ground"],["2","Tank","Ground"]....]

Comment: Do `Debug.Log( loadUnitsWWW.text)` and update me with  what you got.

Comment: @Programmer exact same as the results of Debug.Log(obj)

Comment: I don't do php. I just wanted to check if the problem is from Unity side. It is from the php side. Since you posted your table format, it would be good to also post what you are expecting from the server. Then I will try...

Comment: Updated with what I was expecting :)

Comment: should be `echo json_encode($row);`. but I think you should adding up all the rows and json_encode the entire data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you should be doing this. comment in code

```
// Always use the field names. this is going to avoid debug nightmare later.
$SQL = "SELECT unitID, unitName, unitType FROM `units`";
$Result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL) or die ("DB ERROR");
$Total = mysqli_num_rows($Result);
if($Total > 0)
{
    // initilize a new array
    $data = array();
    // Note use mysqli_fetch_row because you want only result values
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($Result))
    {
        // add the row data to our array
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    // encode the entire data and echo
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Reference : [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Edit: you can also do this like the following.

```
if($Total > 0)
{
    // Get all the result at once and json_encode it!!
    echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($Result));
}
```

Reference: [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Edit2: as per @YourCommonSense comment your code can be

```
$SQL = "SELECT unitID, unitName, unitType FROM `units`";
if ($Result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL))
{
    echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($Result));
} else die ("DB ERROR");
```

Comment: It's better to avoid num rows and total checking. The rest is ok

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I agree, but retained it there, if OP is doing something in the else part. I will add another edit

Comment: I had hoped I could avoid specifying the table fields, as if I wanted to expand upon the table later I'd then have to also change the PHP file. But if it is the best method its not a major issue, just a minor nuisance. Thanks for the response it works perfectly!

Comment: whenever you want to expand/change table fields you normally need change in the code also. so it is not a big burden. But if you are using `*`, you will be having no idea what fields where used, without going through a lot of code. It is just a minor nuisance to begin with, but you will find it much easier later.

Answer (score -1):

`0` refers to column order in the result set. You can refer to [mysqli-result.fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)  and check parameters and return type.
change your line:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
```

with:

```
while($row = $rows) {
 // your code
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQLI_NUM);
}
```

**Another solution, I think it is better for you**

```
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($Result, MYSQLI_NUM);

            echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 issues with your php snippet:

- if you look at the [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) documentation, you'll notice that if you don't supply the second `int $resulttype` argument, it defaults to `MYSQLI_BOTH`; this means that both associative and numeric indices will be returned
- you call `mysqli_fetch_array` on `$Result` twice, first assigning it to `$rows` variable, and second time inside the `while` condition assigning it to the `$row` variable

I'm guessing what you want to do is:

- remove the `$rows` assignment
- inside the `while` condition add the 2nd argument `MYSQLI_NUM`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I originally had actually tried it based on your suggestions. However it returned incorrect data also.